# Unhandled Error has no details and error variable cannot be inspected

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017

I'm working with NodeJS in Visual Studio the first time. Here I get an unhandled error when trying to access a file with `fs.readFile` that does not exist. I cannot hover the *er* variable to inspect all its parameters, the popup doesn't even display the string that was passed in the *Error* constructor.

Is this normal, can it be improved so I can inspect the variables after the break, at least?

[image: capture of the problem]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, I can handle all unexpected errors with the *uncaughtException* handler:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1); // breakpoint here
})
```

So I can inspect the error further.